# difference between "help to live longer" and "help live longer"

Tags: meaning

Is there any differnce in the meanings and/or nuances between the following two sentences?

1. Exercise helps to live longer.
2. Exercise helps live longer.

Comment: This question is better suited for our sister site, ELL or [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). A site dedicated to people who would like to improve their level and understanding of English.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is grammatical, because, in such sentences, *help* needs a direct object, such as *people* or *you*. However, I assume your question is about whether there is any difference between *help* being followed by a **to** infinitive (*to live*) and *help* being followed by a bare infinitive (*live*). The answer to that is that *help* is one of the few verbs which allow both, with no change in meaning.

Comment: I'll risk being caught asking for a list: do you know of any others?

Comment: It can also occur after _had better_ and _would rather_, and after the object of the verbs _make, see, hear_ and _let_. Additionally, it is found in constructions like _What I’ve done is choose only the best answers_ and _All I did was open the door_, and after _rather . . . than_, as in _I’d rather go hungry than live on charity_.

Comment: Sorry, Barrie, are you saying that all these can catenate (with possible intervening objects) with both bare infinitives and to-infinitives? I'm not finding Ngram support for "would rather to _verb_ ", and I don't recognise the expression myself. Thanks for the other examples ('John was heard to say...' is clearly fine whereas the bare infinitive sounds unnatural to me, although the situation is the other way round for 'I heard John say...'. Crazy language.)

Comment: Ah, no. I misread your comment -  and my own answer! Clearly, _would rather_ cannot be followed by **both** the _to_- infinitive and the bare infinitive. Why there’s a difference between the passive (‘was heard to say’) and the active ('I heard John say’) needs more investigation.